# Is there a tool that autodetects which assembly language was used for a certain code?

Tags: assembly

I just stumbled over some assembly code and wanted to assemble it. But I dont know which assembler to use, since I don't know in which assembly language is was written.

Is there a piece of software that identifies the assembly language that was used?

The code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/uExT2Y9h).

Comment: No auto tool I'm aware of, but that looks a bit like inline gcc assembly syntax

Comment: How hard could it possibly be to translate it into your favourite flavour?

Comment: Looks like `as86` syntax.

Comment: What if the favorite flavor uses AT&T syntax? :)

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev According to my experience it's not difficult at all to translate Intel syntax to AT&T syntax (or vice versa) eg. with some Vim or Perl regexes. Other methods also exist.

Comment: I think that a tool like this is impossible...answering your question,I agree with Michael,looks like `as86`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it certainly looks like x86 assembly code based on the registers (CX, etc..).

And based on the fact that it deals with floppy drive sectors, I would venture 8086, 8088 or 80286, 80386, or 80486.

But that's just my guess - it's really difficult to determine based on the info.

Comment: It's 286 bootloader code based on `lmsw`, `lidt` and `ldgt`. It uses 286+ instructions to switch processor to protected mode. I didn't notice any 386+ instructions. Or was there some?